# Are there CentOS/RHEL 7 packages for Twemproxy?

Tags: centos, centos7

I am currently building Twemproxy aka nutcracker (https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy) from source for installing in CentOS 6. And then has to copy the init script using it as a service.

Ubuntu has a packages for Twemproxy at https://launchpad.net/~twemproxy/+archive/ubuntu/stable

Is there a similar repository which has Twemproxy package which bundles the binaries and service files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good search term would be like `twemproxy el7 rpm` It pulled up this

http://dl.marmotte.net/rpms/redhat/el7/x86_64/twemproxy-0.4.1-0.el7/

Comment: Thank you. I was trying centos packages, binaries ..etc etc., and didn't hit anywhere close. I am still looking for something like EPEL. For now I will use this.